# Duplicate Slot Numbers for MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator]

Tags: raid, storage, hardware-raid, megaraid, megacli

Why are duplicate Slot Numbers shown in storcli/Megacli output?

```
# lspci -nn | grep -i mega
01:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] [1000:0079] (rev 03)

# /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL | grep -A 2 'Product Name'
Product Name    : ServeRAID M5015 SAS/SATA Controller
Serial No       : SV03201033
FW Package Build: 12.0.1-0090
```

storcli output...

```
# storcli /c0 /eall /sall show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Information Succeeded.


Drive Information :
=================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                                   Sp 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    11 Rbld   0 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:0    13 Onln   0 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500620NS          81Y9715 81Y3856IBM U  
252:1    10 UGood  - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:1    12 UGood  - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:2     9 UGood  - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:2    14 UGood  - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:3     8 UGood  - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:3    15 UBad   - 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded
enter code here
```

And megacli...

```
# megacli -PDlist -a0 | egrep '^(Enclosure Device ID|Slot Number|Device Id|Inq)'
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 11
Inquiry Data:             9SP1R7B9ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Device Id: 13
Inquiry Data:             9XF06661ST9500620NS          81Y9715 81Y3856IBM BE21    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Device Id: 10
Inquiry Data:             9SP1S0ETST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Device Id: 12
Inquiry Data:             9SP1S09WST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 2
Device Id: 9
Inquiry Data:             9SP1S09QST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 2
Device Id: 14
Inquiry Data:             9SP1WCWRST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Device Id: 8
Inquiry Data:             9SP1S0EXST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16    
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Device Id: 15
Inquiry Data:             9SP1S0DBST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM BE16
```

I have similar server and its output looks ok:

```
# storcli /c0 /eall /sall show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Information Succeeded.


Drive Information :
=================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                                   Sp 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     9 Onln   0 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500620NS          42D0753 42D0756IBM U  
252:1    10 Onln   0 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM U  
252:2    11 Onln   1 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
252:3     8 Onln   1 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
252:4    12 Onln   1 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
252:5    14 Onln   1 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
252:6    13 Onln   2 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
252:7    15 Onln   2 464.729 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9500530NS          42D0743 42D0746IBM D  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded
```

Comment: This might be due to the use of SATA drives with a SAS-capable controller (SATA has 1 channel, SAS drives have two). Can you add more information about your hardware configuration? How are the drives cabled/connected to the controller, and what specific controller model are you using? The LSI 2108 is a ROC that was used on any number of controller models, both "internal" and "external" style.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an IBM server, and after many hours of frustrated debugging, it turned out to be a bad cable between the motherboard and the SAS backplane. So I would start looking at hardware. If you have an identical server, try exchanging parts until something works (that's what I did).